# Add content area within custom class property in Episerver

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I am creating a custom class with the below given definition.
One of the property type given below is of type content area(Media).
[image]
Issue: Since this custom property is in a popup itself, when clicking on the create new block in media content area, it opens the list of blocks to be added behind this popup as shown in the image below(carousal block)
Because of this ,I am unable to add the block within the content area.
.Is there a way to handle this wherein I can add the block within this custom class?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using CMS 11? We've solved that by adding a custom CSS to edit mode and disabling the overlay, allowing access to the Media/Blocks tabs behind the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here but will go ahead and answer it anyway for anyone else in the future who might encounter the same problem. So one option is to go with what Ted Nyberg suggested which will in the end probably provide a cleaner user experience. This is however a bit more advanced approach necessary due to a limitation in the product.

Another approach is to create a block instead of your custom class. This will provide the proper editor experience when working with the content area and will be faster to implement if you have no or little experience with adding custom css to the edit ui.

This goes for CMS versions < 12 and I can't say if this is still a problem in version 12 or not.